# Get object from s3 bucket and display as thumbnail in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm getting objects from s3 and now I want to show them as thumbnails in my react app, so how can I achieve it?

```
var params = {
   Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
   Prefix: 'media',
};
s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else {
        console.log('objects list', data); // successful response
    }
});
```

I'm getting the contents in the response but the question is how can I display them in my app?

**Note**: the bucket is private

Comment: Using class components or function components?

Comment: function component, it should not be  a problem that the component is class or function I think

Comment: are these objects from s3 blobs?

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal I don't get your point?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I had to show thumbnails from an API which was returning blobs since this endpoint was behind oAuth & I couldn't simply give the URL of the image resource. I'm assuming you are also receiving an octet-stream.

Here's what my axios call looked like:

```
images(id: string, cancelToken?: CancelToken): Promise<FileResponse> {
 let url_ = "pathtoendpoint/{id}";

 let options_ = <AxiosRequestConfig>{
   cancelToken,
   responseType: "blob",
   method: "GET",
   url: url_,
   headers: {
     Accept: "application/octet-stream",
     Authorization: "Bearer ezfsdfksf...."
   },
 };

    
 return Axios.create().request(options_).then((_response: AxiosResponse) => 
 { 
   return new Promise<FileResponse>(_response.data);
 });

} 

export interface FileResponse {
  data: Blob;
  status: number;
  fileName?: string;
  headers?: { [name: string]: any };
}
```

I then create an ephemeral DOM string containing a uri

```
let uri = URL.createObjectURL(data)
```

Once I have the uri then I can display it as so

```
<img src={uri} id="someId" alt="" />
```

If it helps my server side code likes like so,

```
[Produces("application/octet-stream")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetImageById([FromRoute] Guid id)
{
    var resource = await DatalayerService.GetImageAsync(id);

    return File(resource.Filebytes, resource.ContentType);
}
```